# QPushButton иконка над текстом

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

Как расположить иконку QPushButton над задаваемым текстом? Расположение по центру.

Comment: на англоязычном stackoverflow всплывал такой вопрос, там был совет вместо QPushButton писать QToolButton и setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon); но мне такой вариант не подходит, т.к. при QToolButton иконка прилипает к верхней границе кнопки.

Comment: Напечатайте текст непосредственно в картинке. (Используйте SVG если нужно менять текст, например, при переводе.)

Comment: Да, текст нужно будет изменить. Ну, хорошо, я подложу его на кнопку через QPushButton::setIcon(QIcon(":/icon.svg"));
А как потом текст изменить (перевести)?

Comment: Может быть иконку задавать отдельно, а кнопку отдельно? Сделать такой составной виджет?

Comment: Можно сказать, ответ был найден - никак.
В итоге решено было наследоваться и перерисовываться в `paintEevetn()`.
Всем спасбо